# Display SQL parameter in Input Values prompt

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2005

I added a parameter to my SQL query in the Parameter fields. (I went to *Edit Command* and created a new param for the query.)

When I run the query, the *input values* popup does not include an area to input my new param. How do I add this?

Comment: Is problem solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey ya I was able to solve it. Basically I had to go into the command and set up a new param. Run it without being able to enter my new param. Hit verify database now enter new param. Went back into command and then I was able to get it working correctly. Thanks